# Which is more stable, a secondary allylic carbanion or a primary allylic carbanion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, stability, resonance

I came across this picture in a polymer chemistry course, specifically on anionic polymerization of conjugated dienes (butadiene).
[image: conjugated diene carbanion resonance]

I dont understand why the secondary carbanion is more stable. Based on what I know, inductive effects should destabilize the secondary carbanion, so the primary carbanion will be preferred. Moreover, the hybridization and pi orbital orientation of the two ions seems to be the same.

For extra context, the carbanion could exist as an ion pair with Li+ as the counterion, although it should exist as a free ion in the most part since the solvent is polar. However, this also doesnt explain why the second structure is more stable.